# Get specific product with id via Rest API Magento 2

Tags: rest, magento2

I want to get the information from an specific product.

I am using this reference in this moment, and get all the products in given searchCriteria:

http://www.mysite.co/rest/V1/products-render-info?storeId=1&currencyCode=cop

Is there a way I can send the product `id` in the url and get only all its information?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the filter

```
http://www.mysite.co/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

use field **entity_id** instead of **id**, value is product id here **1**, condition_type is equal to here **eq**.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch product info by SKU, not ID.

API endpoint (get method) will pull product info. `vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/webapi.xml`

```
/V1/products/:sku
```

So, your rest API calling URL should be like this

```
http://www.mysite.co/rest/V1/products/productsku
```

Note: If you want to fetch product info by id, you probably need to create a simple rest API. you can check this out.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/282480/i-am-new-here-i-want-to-know-how-can-i-create-my-own-simple-api/282730